# Mutation Test tools in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, mutation-testing

I am starting a new project in c# and I am looking for a tool that helps me do mutation tests. I have previously done mutation testing in java using [pitest](http://pitest.org/) and liked it very much.
Now I am looking for such a tool for C# and the only ones i can find are either not updated for the past few years or still in alpha/beta
( [cream](http://galera.ii.pw.edu.pl/~adr/CREAM/index.php), [ninjaTurtles](https://ninjaturtles.codeplex.com/), [Nester](http://nester.sourceforge.net/)).

Are there any tools available that are reliable and can be used with tools that came out after 2010?

EDIT:
Some might say this question is a duplicate of [What mutation-testing frameworks exist? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246495/what-mutation-testing-frameworks-exist). Only that question is currently 8 years old and most of the tools discussed there are not usable since most of them haven't been updated in the last 6 to 8 years.

Comment: Nester was the one that i was talking about (needed Visual Studio 2005). Hope you can do all the needed work with VisualMutator.Net.

Comment: That the other question is out-of-date does not prevent your question from being a duplicate. Especially since your question is also off-topic: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used with success the following Visual Studio 2013 extension: VisualMutator.Net. That's because other mutation tools needed Visual Studio 2005 in place or other uber obsolete software / frameworks / so on.

More here: http://visualmutator.github.io/web/

You will basically get a UI like the one below:

[image: Tests that can be runned]

`TestingExample.Tests` will be mutated. Probably you already have your project structured `Project & Project.Tests`
You have access to the following list of mutans:

ISD (ISK) – Super/Base Keyword Deletion

Operator deletes a call for base class method in overloading method belonging to inheritance method.

DMC – Delegated Method Change

Operator changes a method of processing delegation into another one with similar signature.

DEH – Method Delegated for Event Handling Change

Operator changes a call adding or removing a method from error handling. EAM,

EMM – Accessors, Modifier Method Change

Operators change a call for class property into call for another property of the same type. EHR -

Exception Handler Removal

Operator removes catch block if there exists another catch or finally.

EHC – Exception Handling Change

Operator changes body of a catch block into throwing caught exception.

EXS – Exception Swallowing

Operator adds empty block catch(Exception e) so that no exception can leave current method.

JTI, JTD – This Keyword Insertion, Deletion

Operators add or remove this keyword if there exists local variable with the same name.

JID – Member Variable Initialization Deletion (Field Initialization Deletion) Operator deletes

initialisation of class's field with proper value.

MCI – Member Call from Another Inherited Class

Operator changes calling of a method on object into calling the same method on another object.

PRV - Reference Assignment with Other Compatible Type

Operator changes assigning certain object to references into assigning another compatible object.

Standard Operators:

AOR – Arithmetic Operator Replacement

Operator changes arithmetical operations (+, -, *, /, %) into another one from this group.

LOR – Logical Operator Replacement

Operator changes logical operations (&, |, ˆ) into another one from this group.

LCR – Logical Connector Replacement

Operator changes connector (,||) in logic expression into another one.

ROR – Relational Operator Replacement

Operator changes each relational operator (>, <, <=, >=, ==, !=) into another one from the same group.

SOR – Shift Operator Replacement

Operator changes logical shift (», «) into opposite one.

OODL – Operator Deletion

Operator creates two mutants from each operation such as +,-,>,<=,% etc. In one it removes operation

and what is on its left side, in the other one it removes operation and what is on its right side (e.g. from y=a+b; there will be following mutants : y=a; and y=b;).

SSDL – Statement Block Deletion

Operator removes statements and assignments, but not declarations (e.g. from int y=15; there will be following mutant: int y;).

And results are looking like the following:

**Mutation score**
[image: Mutation score]

**Not killed mutant**
[image: Not killed mutant]

**Killed mutant**
[image: Killed mutant]

**By the following tests**

[image: Killed mutant by the following]